# How to correct Errno 13 in Python?

Tags: python

So a few Days ago I asked a similar question, but now I understand my issue a little bit better.
I am still receiving the error 13 in python and I am denied permission. I trying to open my excel sheet onto python, but I think I'm trying to open a directory as a file and that is my issue. I don't really know how else to open this so any tips to adjust my code would be amazing.

```
    import csv
with open("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Google Drive\\Computer Science 1\\dlighted\\AI-Radar.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

This is the error I keep receiving as well:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Google Drive\\Computer Science 1\\dlighted\\AI-Radar.csv'
```

Comment: Well according to your Error you do not have permission to access the file. Maybe try and close the file, in case it is opened. Or try your script with administrator priviliges.

Comment: ^This. User folders in Windows are restricted to that user. Admin privileges should help with that. +For Google Drive location there might some other limitations because the Google Drive keeps track of the files in some way. You can test whether there are problems with that by copying the file outside Google Drive location and testing script with new location.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if file is not already open. Better to kill excel processes in task manager.

[image: Kill Excel Processes]